# Google charts axis rendering issue on Android Honeycomb Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, google-visualization

I am about to release an update to my application to use the new JavaScript [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) having taken note of the deprecation warning against the [Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/). I am encountering JavaScript issues with the axis labelling apparently dependent on the version of the Android WebKit. I am aware that using the Google Charts API *simply won't work* pre-3.1 owing to the lack of SVG support within the Webkit client.

#### Background

The application currently supports Eclair (API Level 7) upward with SVG support only arriving on the in-built WebKit client in Honeycomb MR1 (API Level 12). To address this discrepancy in functionality my code employs a simple if-else statement inspecting the Android version prior to deciding which charting API to use.

#### The rendering issue

This is best shown with a picture. Please note that;

1. The same JavaScript is being run on the Android Honeycomb Emulator as on the Jelly Bean device.
2. The comparison is between an emulator (not working) and a real phone (working)
3. The JavaScript is being run from within a WebView leveraging the in-built `android.webkit.WebViewClient`
4. The axis on the emulator show as `[Object object]` but correctly on the real device

[image: Chart showing the axis labelling issue]

*Figure 1* - The incorrect axis labelling found on the Honeycomb Emulator.

[image: Chart showing the correct axis labelling]

*Figure 2* - The correct axis labelling found on the Real device.

#### The code

Without 'paste-bombing' the issue with masses of irrelevant code the bits of JS and Java driving the naming of the vertical (v) axis are described below;

*JavaScript*

```
...
As part of the chart options...
...
// Vertical axis.
vAxis: {title: yAxisTitle.toString(),
        baselineColor: 'white',
        titleTextStyle: {color: 'gray'},
        textStyle: {color: 'gray'}, 
        gridlines: {color: 'gray'}
        }
```

where `yAxisTitle` has been injected in via the Android `WebView.addJavascriptInterface` like so;

*Java*

```
chart.addJavascriptInterface(String.format(getString(string.height_label), getUnits().getSymbol()), "yAxisTitle");
```

#### Investigation to date

From briefly encountering the `[Object object]` description previously (I'm new to the world of JS) I understand that I am simply executing a toString on a JavaScript object and that's what it looks like. But does this mean there has been a change in Java-JavaScript injection between Android 3.1 and 4.1 which means the datatypes being inject via the *addJavascriptInterface* are now being 'remembered' whereas previously they were not? Should I be serialising the string into a JSON object or is that overkill for what is passing an (almost) primitive type? Finally should I be explicitly casting on the JS side to enforce that the sorts of objects being used for items such as axis labels are indeed strings? Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `WebChromeClient` console to log the results of a number of different permutations on the *inject and parse* approach I described in the question. I discovered that the type is not 'lost' across various version of Android and no amount of casting or other tomfoolery will correct the situation described.

In place of the approach I injected a `JSONObject` describing the axis title and parsed the object in the JS. See below;

*Java*

```
final JSONObject axes = new JSONObject();
axes.put("yAxisTitle", String.format(getString(string.height_label), getUnits().getSymbol()));
axes.put("zAxisTitle", getString(string.period_label));
chart.addJavascriptInterface(axes, "axes");
```

*JavaScript*

```
vAxis: {title: chartAxes.yAxisTitle,
        baselineColor: 'white',
        titleTextStyle: {color: 'gray'},
        textStyle: {color: 'gray'}, 
        gridlines: {color: 'gray'}
       },
```

And this works across Android versions. Lesson learnt- don't attempt Java-JS comms without JSON, even if the datatypes are basic - no big surprises there.

Comment: Also encountered a further issue with the 4.2 JS security enhancements. Have a read of [CommonsGuy's blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/02/18/webview-addjavascriptinterface-change.html) if you found your way here after having 4.2 JS issues.

Comment: Can we give animations to this charts ?